# Convert equation in string format to Line(geometry) object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a linear equation like `y = "x+1"` in my python code. I want to convert this equation into an object of class Line in sympy as `sympy.geometry.line`. I tried to parse the string into sympy expression by doing:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, standard_transformations, function_exponentiation, implicit_multiplication_application)
y = "2*x+1"
transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
L2 = parse_expr(y, transformations=transformations)
print(type(L2))
```

and output is `<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>`.

I do not know what to do next to make it to object. If it is not possible, then is there a way to convert it into another object of a class, like a python scipy Line object?

I need this because I want to calculate the slope of the line, points lying on the line (points that satisfies the equation) to calculate lines parallel or perpendicular to this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a simple way to create a Line object from an equation. I think the simplest way to do it would be to create two Point objects from two x values (say 0 and 1) and create the line from those, like

```
p1 = Point(0, L2.subs(x, 0))
p2 = Point(1, L2.subs(x, 1))
Line(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature now exists in Sympy, for anyone else who finds this post.

I tested this in Sympy 1.5.1

**Code:**

```
from sympy import Line, symbols

a,b,c,x,y = symbols('a b c x y')

# Hardcoded line equation
line1 = Line(3*x + 1*y + 18)
print(line1)

# Set the line equation in code
a = 3; b = 1; c = 18
line2 = Line(a*x + b*y + c)
print(line2)
```

**Output:**

> Line2D(Point2D(0, -18), Point2D(1, -21))
> Line2D(Point2D(0, -18), Point2D(1, -21))

Unfortunately it fails for vertical lines:
1*x + 0*y - 100
outputs
ValueError: could not find y